# How to init subview into superview with the superview size , in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I try to init the subview page with the original superview.

This should be a view page on the view page.

This method call from viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)CreateDarkerView
{
  UIView *darker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.verificationView.frame];
  darker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  darker.alpha = 0.7;
  [verificationView insertSubview:darker aboveSubview:blurBackground];


  NSLog(@"darker height = %f ",(darker.frame.size.height));
  NSLog(@"darker width = %f  \n",(darker.frame.size.width));

  NSLog(@"VerificationView height = %f ",(self.verificationView.frame.size.height));
  NSLog(@"VerificationView width = %f \n\n ",(self.verificationView.frame.size.width));



}
```

No matter which simulator I run (4s,5,5s,6,6+) This frame sizes remain constant.

This is a Printout from console line.

```
2014-09-29 15:33:32.652 roee[33353:5476056] darker height = 568.000000 
2014-09-29 15:33:32.653 roee[33353:5476056] darker width = 320.000000  

2014-09-29 15:33:32.653 roee[33353:5476056] VerificationView height = 568.000000 
2014-09-29 15:33:32.653 roee[33353:5476056] VerificationView width = 320.000000
```

And for example when the simulator opens I can see that screens is not in the same size.
The darker view is small from the Verification View.

I use auto layout to the VerificationView in Xcode Version 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not guaranteed to have proper geometry on `viewDidLoad`. Use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instad for calling `-(void)createDarkerView`.

Comment: By the way, I forgot: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` may be called multiple times. Make sure to add a flag so `createDarkerView` is only executed once.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `-initWithFrame:` with `self.verificationView.bounds` instead.